# python pycurl connection timeout problems

Tags: python, connection-timeout, pycurl

I set both connection timeout and timeout to 30s in the program, but it always throw connection timeout at 7s, are there other settings taking control of the time?  (my program runs on centos 7 and python2.7)

```
c.setopt(pycurl.CONNECTTIMEOUT, 30)
c.setopt(pycurl.TIMEOUT, 30)
```

Comment: Are you behind some proxy network?

Comment: my machine locates inside  priviate network, there  must be some  network nat equipments translating the request (but i don't know what they are), you mean it has something with the nat equipments？

Comment: If you are inside a private network you need to go past the proxy to complete the request. `c.setopt(pycurl.PROXY, self.proxy['proxy_host'])` and `c.setopt(pycurl.PROXYPORT, self.proxy['proxy_port'])` and if you need to use user and password to go past the proxy then `c.setopt(pycurl.PROXYUSERPWD, "%(proxy_user)s:%(proxy_pass)s" % self.proxy)`

Comment: you may misunderstand it,  nat equipments are network hardwares and they do some network translating work which are transparent to me.

Comment: if that is the case you may have to first check if normal `curl` works on your system and identify the dependencies. If that works fine we can implement the same for `pycurl`

Comment: pycurl.CONNECTTIMEOUT  option worked in the private network, there must be some problems with network devices, thanks a lot!

Comment: Please cast your vote on suggestions if it works. It helps.